# WebApi GET and multiple POST parameter without model always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying send both parameter get and post to method on service without model but it's always null. How can i solve this problem? Also what is logical reason of this problem? Codes as follow which i encountered problem;

```
[HttpGet]
public Result GetUser(string userId)
{
    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
    {
        return dc.GetUser(userId);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public Result CreateUser([FromBody]string firstname, [FromBody]string lastname)
{
    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
    {
        return dc.CreateUser(firstname, lastname);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to do it without a model?

Comment: Could you also post your ajax request call, your question is incomplete without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do in the Post request is not valid as per the HTTP protocol. Each web request can only have 1 body, and while it is possible to pass a single param in a unstructured form it is not possible with two (source Asp.net website [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) ). Hence you have 2 options:

1). Add the 2 params to the url - Change the [FromBody] to [FromUri]

2). Encapsulate both params into a class/model, and accept this as input to your post method (from body or URL/URi will both work). The sender of the data will be able to specify how they wish to send this, via xml or json, by default with asp.net Web api

Comment: thanks for your recommend. I have just inspect document which you specied above.

Answer (score 3):

The 'FromBody' attribute can only be used for a single parameter on a method, so marking both of them with 'FromBody' won't work.
You can create a simple model that contains 'firstname' and 'lastname' as properties and have a parameter of that type for the post method.

Another solution is to use a dynamic object obtained from parsing the Json to get your properties.

dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

string firstname = foo.firstname;

string lastname = foo.lastname;

Answer (score -1):

Sample ajax call for consume your web api

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:49493/api/Values",
        type: "Get",
        data: {'userId' : 1}
        success: function (data) { 
            /// process data
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
```